How to dynamially get hostnames of all Active Directory servers for a specific domain?
I'm writing an application on a UNIX-like operating system that uses my work's Active Directory setup for authentication (and possibly authorization). I know how to authenticate and interact with a specific LDAP server, but how do I programmatically get a list of Active Directory servers for a specific domain (both the master/primary controller and all the slave/secondary controllers)?
I know there's also the concept of "closest" or "best" AD domain controller. I can always hard-code a specific server in my application, but if that one goes down then my code will stop working. I think Active Directory uses certain records/patterns/conventions in DNS to list all domain controllers but I'm not sure how that works. This pseudocode is roughly what I'm trying to do:
connection_successful = false
mylist = fetch list of available DC's for SOME.AD.DOMAIN
sort mylist based on "natural" order (e.g. primary first, followed by secondaries)
foreach hostname in mylist:
  c = attemp_connection(hostname)
  if (c):
    connection_successful = true
    authenticate user + other logic
    exit loop
if (not connection_successful):
  display "unable to connect to any of the available DCs"


Once you make a bind to a domain controller in the domain, You can use a simple query like
(&(objectCategory=Computer)(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=8192))

Will provide a list of all "Domain Controllers".
More examples are at https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Active%20Directory%20Computer%20Related%20LDAP%20Query#section-Active+Directory+Computer+Related+LDAP+Query-AllDomainControllers

This assumes I'm already connected to AD. The bit I'm interested in is getting the addresses of the AD servers, which I can then iterate over until I get a connection and run my queries.
